# Unable to find the Entity relative to a proxy

Tags: symfony

I have a simple Request on a Contact table.

```
use App\Entity\Contact;
...
        $contact = $this->getUser()->getContact();
        $form = $this->createForm(ParentContactType::class,$contact);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

But when Handling the form, Symfony throws following Exception:
`Unable to find the object manager associated with an entity of class "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Contact".`

The contact Class is a normal one,

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ContactRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ContactRepository::class)
 */
#[ApiResource]
class Contact
{
    const FIRST_CONTACT = "Contact principal";
    const SECOND_CONTACT = "Second contact";
    const THIRD_CONTACT = "Troisième contact";
    
    public function __construct(){
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
     */
    private $gender;
+ getter and setter
```

It used to be working fine, but I do not know how to debug the issue.
Any help would be great.

Comment: please show App\Entity\Contact class code

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes, and still nor working. I'll further investigate. Merci pour ton aide.